# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72510Library'

Tags: java, android-studio

So I opened my app the next day and it said this error. 
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72510Library'.

> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\Jenna\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\appcompat-v7-25.1.0.aar'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I'm not exactly sure what this error means and I didn't change anything about the file (to my knowledge). If anyone could help with a step by step way to fix this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: * What went wrong:
Could not read path 'C:\Users\Jenna\Downloads\ChargerPoints-master\ChargerPoints-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\res\values-hy-rAM'.
> C:\Users\Jenna\Downloads\ChargerPoints-master\ChargerPoints-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\res\values-hy-rAM: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.